# Custom tooltip names Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts pie chart and I want to add custom suffix for each point. For example now I have this in the tooltip formatter:

`tooltip : {
             formatter : function() {
                  return 'Daily KB: <b>'+ this.point.y +'</b>';
                     }
           },`

and the way the pop up is displayed is something like that for each piece of the pie `Daily KB: 300`. How can I modify this so that in one piece the pop up will be somehting like this `Daily KB: 700 remaining` and the other will be `Daily KB: 300`?

```
Highcharts script:
(function($){
    $(this.document).ready(function(){
        //get local time
    Highcharts.setOptions({
            colors: ['#fa604c', '#00CC66']
    });;
        myChart_d = new Highcharts.Chart({

     chart: {
         height:200,
         width:200,
         type: 'pie',
         animation: false,
         renderTo: 'dailychart',
         zoomType: 'x',

           events:  {
            load: function () {
                requestDataLim();

            }
        }

        },
     title: {
        text: 'Daily'
    },
     tooltip : {
                    formatter : function() {
           return 'Daily KB: <b>'+ this.point.y +'</b>';
        }
                },
    //tooltip: {
            //shared:true
        //},
      plotOptions: {
        pie: {
           //   allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,

                },
            borderColor: '#A0A0A0',
            innerSize: '40%',

        },
        series:{
           dataLabels: {
               style:{ fontSize: '14px', fontWeight:'bold' },
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    return Math.round(this.percentage) + ' %';
                },
                distance: -15,
                color:'black'
            } 
        },
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{

        name: 'DailyKB',
        data: 
            [<?php echo join(',',$d); 
                  echo ',';
                  echo join (',',$dl);?>]




    }],
exporting: {
buttons: {
    printButton: {
        enabled: false
    },
    exportButton: {
        enabled: false
    }    
}
```

}

```
});
```

I get me data through ajax and JSON and currently are something like this `[300, 700]`

Comment: Please share your whole highcharts script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about changing format fo data to array of objects? For example:

```
 [{y: 300, suffix: ""}, {y: 700, suffix: " remaining" }]
```

Then in tooltip set add `suffix` info:

```
return 'Daily KB: <b>'+ this.point.y +'</b>' + this.point.options.suffix;
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that but I tried it and it works fine! Thanks for the help!!